# Android Set ImageView Animation from String

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

I am currently trying to play an animation in a ImageView.

This code is working fine:

```
//Run Animations
    ImageView char1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.char1);
    //set the animation drawable as background
    char1.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.male03idle);
    //create an animation drawable using the background
    AnimationDrawable char1anim = (AnimationDrawable) char1.getBackground();
    //start the animation
    char1anim.start();
```

I want to use a String to point to this animation in R.anim.

for example:

```
String char1resource = "male" + "03" + "idle";
```

and then use char1resource in char1.setBackgroundResource.

I've Tried something like this but it doesn't work:

```
String c1r = "male" + "03" + "idle";
    int char1Resource = getResources().getIdentifier(c1r, null, getPackageName());
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(char1Resource);


  //Run Animations
    ImageView char1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.char1);
    //set the animation drawable as background
    char1.setBackgroundResource(image);
    //create an animation drawable using the background
    AnimationDrawable char1anim = (AnimationDrawable) char1.getBackground();
    //start the animation
    char1anim.start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I wasn't declaring the source location.

"anim/" + "male" + "03" + "idle"